# improving least squares solution after adding more observations points

Tags: algorithms, least-squares

You fit a simple linear model  $y=\sum{c_i \times x_i}+q$ to your data $X=\{x_{ij}\}$ and $Y=\{y_j\}$ by linear least squares, and you obtain a solution $(q,c_i)$ (plus the residual variance) as a function of the N observations that you provided to the calulation.

How does that solution transform into the updated one $(q',c'_i)$, when we have longer data vectors $X'$ and $Y'$?

Is there any closed form expression that uses only the added points and some sort of "condensed" information saved from the previous fit?

Comment: If you use the normal equations, you can update the summations for the new points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least-squares fitting is performed from the normal equations, which consist essentially in the variance-covariance matrix, obtained by accumulating the moments up to second order.

This is the condensed form you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*I do not know if this is what you are looking for.*

Suppose that you solve the problem using the normal equations and use matrices for solving the linear system. This means (for a model with two variables) you solved $$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=nc_0+c_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}+c_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}y_i=c_0\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}+c_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}^2+c_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}x_{2i}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}y_i=c_0\sum_{i=1}^nx_{21i}+c_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}x_{2i}+c_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}^2$$ Now, you add $p$ new data points; so the equations become
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}y_i\right)=(n+p)c_0+c_1\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{1i}\right)+c_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{2i}\right)$$ $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}y_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{1i}y_i\right)=c_0\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{1i}\right)+c_1\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}^2+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{1i}^2\right)+c_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}x_{2i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{1i}x_{2i}\right)$$ 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}y_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{2i}y_i\right)=c_0\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{2i}\right)+c_1\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}x_{2i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{1i}x_{2i}\right)+c_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}^2+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}x_{2i}^2\right)$$ Since you saved the $\sum_{i=1}^n(.)$, you just need to compute the $\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p}(.)$ which update the coefficients of the linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, provided that you add just one point and you always store not just the previous model $\beta_n$ but also the corresponding (squared) matrix $R_n$:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66950/intuition-for-recursive-least-squares